# Assistance with debugging views in Laravel

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, laravel-blade

I always find it quite hard to debug issues in the view as I can't find a line where the error occurred... It states what property may have been called wrong but it's sometimes hard to find the issue from just this... I'd love a line number.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you miss something. That is how it works. Sometimes you get error and it's really hard to guess what the error is about in Laravel. If you have problems with that you could try using debugger (for example xdebug) to find the source of problem.

Comment: I do use Xdebug in netbeans... and I will try this, but does it not just skip over the view part, it won't freeze at that line? I'll give it a try but oh well, what a bummer about lack of line numbering... would be schaaaweeeet

Answer (score 0):

As @Marcin mentioned, you can possibly try to use a debugger like X-Debug, but even if you can get the IDE to enable breakpoints on the Blade files, it won't work - Laravel composes a PHP file from the Blade file - it is this file that is eventually used when the script is run - not the Blade file.

**A Work-Around**

This works for PHPStorm - but something similar might be possible in other IDEs.

Laravel (5) stores the composed files under storage/framework/views.
These files have random generated file names - so it may be tricky to find the file you want.
An easy way is to delete all these temp files and then refresh the page you want to debug. A new file will be created.
In PHPstorm you can right-click on the file and select the file's extension type. (Not sure about other IDEs)

You will now be able to set breakpoints. Obviously you will need to make the changes in the Blade file - but this will at least help you to figure out what is wrong.